# _POST empty if file size exceeds 3M in php

Tags: php, post, upload

I have a form that submits multiple image files to be uploaded to the server. The code works fine for 2 files but as soon as I add a third file it stops working and the $_POST data becomes blank.

I checked stackoverflow and have ensured that in my php.ini file the post_max_size is set to 128M. Other relevant parameters are mentioned below:

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Is there some other setting that I need to fix? Tried researching quite a bit but couldnt find an exact fit.

Comment: Have you restarted the Xampp or Wampp?

Comment: Run  `phpinfo()` to check memory limit and all parameter related to memory.

Comment: yes i did. in fact the php.ini always had these values. I am encountering this on wamp.

Comment: did you test with single file upload with apprx. 50MB. Is that working?

Comment: I checked phpinfo and it says post_max_size as 3M whereas in the php.ini  it is saying 128M .... any ideas if there is an alternate location of php.ini from where wamp picks it up? I am searching in wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini

Comment: Looks like i was making changes in the wrong php.ini file. I found the correct file and there it indeed was 3M. Thanks all.

Comment: after running `phpinfo()` you can check you php.ini path. recheck that